# Is the phrase "has a few investors worried" standard English?

Tags: present-perfect

> The CFO is stepping down after five years of service, and this change in the executive team **has a few investors worried**.

Is the selected phrase a standard English? Does it mean the same as "has worried a few investors"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes. It means the change [causes](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/have) them to be worried.

You can have somebody do something, which means you cause/order/persuade them to do it.

And you can have somebody be in a particular state (worried, excited, riled up).